# Erro ao conectar uma câmera por IP ao OpenCv (-215:Assertion failed)

Tags: python, opencv

Boa tarde, gente! Tudo bem?
 Então, eu estou tentando conectar uma webcam por ip ao open cv, a webcam seria a câmera do meu celular e estou usando o droid cam para isso.
 Acontecem que sempre me deparo com esse erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/uriel/Documents/Python/Project #1/droidcam.py", line 10, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('IPWebcam',img)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'
```

Aqui está o meu código completo:

```
import urllib.request
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
URL = "http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:xxxx/"
while True:
    img_arr = np.array(bytearray(urllib.request.urlopen(URL).read()),dtype=np.uint8)
    img = cv2.imdecode(img_arr,-1)
    #imS = cv2.resize(img,(960, 540))
    cv2.imshow('IPWebcam',img)

    if cv2.waitKey(0):
        break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se conseguir acessar sua câmera colocando o ip no navegador, tente:

```
import cv2

ip = "http://xxxx/?action=stream"  #colocar o ip da camera
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(ip)

_, img = cam.read()

cv2.imshow('frame', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```